# comparing estimators for variance, cofusion about biases and mean square errors

Tags: variance, estimation, bias, estimators

I wanted to compare biases and mean square errors for three estimators of variance. I took one unbiased (first) estimator and two biased.

```
W1=c()
W2=c()
W3=c()
n=5000
for(i in 1:1000)
{
  X=rnorm(n,0,2)
  S_n=sum((X-sum(X)/n)^2)/(n-1)  
  S1_n=((n-1)*(S_n))/(n) 
  S2_n=((n-1)*(S_n))/(n+1)  
  
  W1=c(W1,S_n) 
  W2=c(W2,S1_n)
  W3=c(W3,S2_n)
}
B1=mean(W1)-4
B2=mean(W2)-4
B3=mean(W3)-4

RMSE1=sqrt(mean(W1-4)^2)
RMSE2=sqrt(mean(W2-4)^2)
RMSE3=sqrt(mean(W3-4)^2)
```

Firstly I create 3 lists where I will add estimated values for each of 1000 rounds of sampling 5000 numbers from normal distribution with 0 mean and and 4 variance. Then I calculate 3 estimators and add them to the lists as I mentioned before. After for loop ends I have 3 lists of estimated values and then I calculate biases and square roots of mean square errors.

Even without simulation, just by looking at formulas you see that if S_n happen to be positive then unbiased estimator is further from 4 than unbiased ones. Why bias is even useful then? Note that the unbiased estimators are closer to the parameter half of the times, so I am confused.

Wikipedia says that second estimator have smaller mean square error, when I run this code it is sometimes smaller sometimes bigger, but it is not the case that most of the time it is smaller (it probably is if wikipedia says so but it is unseenable when I run it say 20 times). How should I modify my code to see it really is smaller? I mean I should probably run this code many times and somehow store and compare the data, how should I do it?

Maybe I have something wrong in the code in the first place.